# ipython prompt and the inputting command twinkle

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

python2.7.10,ipython5.0.0,linux

when I use my ipython console, the prompt and the inputting command is always twinkling, and I uninstall it and reinstall again, but the error occur again, I googled and did find any answer about it

Comment: Twinkling? I've never seen that. The prompt and input is redrawn on each keystroke, but terminals generally do that without any flicker. What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: I didn't mean that, the prompt and input will twinkle all the time without doing anyting,  and when I type "help('modules')", there was a warnning about the kernel, I had installed ipython4, it was OK.thanks!

Comment: Weird. No idea what would cause that :-S

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SecureCRT, change the following settings, select Linux (I haven't tested other options), don't select ANSI, if you are using other terminals such as XShell, there are similar settings.
[image]